# MSAL asks for login again (SSO) issue with flutter in iOS

Tags: flutter, azure-ad-msal

Hello in my mobile application I am using the msal_mobile plugin to sign-in to an Azure AD B2C identity provider.

The problem is it asks for a login again in webview or custom tab when navigating to a website the user is already authorized to view, this is the case even if you redirect to browser but according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/customize-webviews#cookie-sharing-and-single-sign-on-sso-implications) cookies are stored and SSO should work if you use `ASWebAuthenticationSession` or `SFAuthenticationSession` but it is still asking me to login.

So my questions are

1. is it possible to achieve SSO using webview?
2. is there any other way to get cookies or keep session from msal_mobile plugin & set it to system browser or browser cache

plugin : [msal_mobile](https://pub.dev/packages/msal_mobile)

Comment: Hi @Suj. Did you manage to solve this issue? I am also facing the same in my flutter app.

Comment: Yes, kindly refer following package https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth